# Tic Tac Toe project_I am stuck

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I currently doing this tic tac toe project, but I am stuck because it does not work, so I need help identifying what errors I made. In addition, I need to allow the user to choose one letter ("X" o "O") and the "X" goes first. I don't know how can I code this. I hope that someone help me, please.

This is the code that I have developed:

```
# Variables globales



# Tablero vacio

board = ["_", "_", "_",
         "_", "_", "_",
         "_", "_", "_",]


# Si juego continua 
juego_continua = True # El juego continua desde el inicio.

# Quien gana o empata
ganador = None

# Turno asignado
actual_jugador = "X"


# Funcion que defin juego tic tac toe.
def jugar_juego (): #

  display_board() # Se va a representar el tablero inicial en pantalla.

  # Mientras el juego continua.
  while juego_continua: # Booleano

    # Definir un solo turno para un jugador arbitrario
    handle_turn (actual_jugador)

    # Verificar si se acabo el juego
    verificar_si_termino_juego()

    # Cambiar al otro jugador
    cambio_jugador()

    # El juego ha terminado

  if ganador == "Jugador - X" or ganador == "Jugador - O":
      print(ganador + "Ganaste.")
  elif ganador == None:
      print ("Hay empate.")

def display_board(): 
   print ("\n")
   print (board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + "     1 | 2 | 3")
   print (board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + "     4 | 5 | 6")
   print (board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + "     7 | 8 | 9")
   print ("\n")

    
     # Define un turno para el jugador arbitrariamente.
def handle_turn(jugador):

    print(jugador + "turno.")
    posicion = input("Elegir una posicion desde 1 hasta 9 para comenzar: ")
    
    valid = False
    while not valid:

     while posicion not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" ]:
      posicion = input("Por favor elegir una posicion desde 1 hasta 9 para jugar: ")
    
    posicion = int(posicion) - 1

    if board (posicion) == "_":
        valid = True
    else:
        print ("Esta posición ya esta ocupada, elegir otra: ")

    
    board[posicion] = jugador
    
    display_board()

def verificar_si_termino_juego():
    verificar_si_gano()
    verificar_si_empate()
 
def verificar_si_gano():
    
    # Establecer variable global
    global ganador

    # verificar filas
    ganador_filas = check_filas()
    # verificar columnas
    ganador_columnas = check_columnas()
    # verificar diagonales
    ganador_diagonales = check_diagonales()
    if ganador_filas:
        ganador = ganador_filas

    elif ganador_columnas:
        ganador = ganador_columnas
        
    elif ganador_diagonales:
        ganador = ganador_diagonales
      
    else:
        #No hay ganador
        ganador = None
    


def check_filas():
    # Establecer variable global
    global juego_continua
    # Revisa si las filas son iguales, exceptuando "_"
    fila_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "_" 
    fila_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != "_" 
    fila_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != "_" 
    # Si alguna fila es igual, indica que hay un ganador
    if fila_1 or fila_2 or fila_3:
        juego_continua = False
        # Devuelve el ganador (X o O)
    if fila_1:
        return board[0]
    elif fila_2:
        return board[3]
    elif fila_3:
        return board[6]
    # Retorna ninguna si no hay ganador
    else:
      return None

def check_columnas():
    # Establecer variable global
    global juego_continua
    # Revisa si las columnas son iguales, exceptuando "_"
    columnas_1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != "_" 
    columnas_2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != "_" 
    columnas_3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != "_" 
    # Si alguna columna es igual, indica que hay un ganador
    if columnas_1 or columnas_2 or columnas_3:
        juego_continua = False
        # Devuelve el ganador (X o O)
    if columnas_1:
        return board[0]
    elif columnas_2:
        return board[1]
    elif columnas_3:
        return board[2]
    else:
      return None

def check_diagonales():
     # Establecer variable global
    global juego_continua
    # Revisa si las diagonales son iguales, exceptuando "_"
    diagonal_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != "_" 
    diagonal_2 = board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != "_" 
  
    # Si alguna diagonal es igual, indica que hay un ganador
    if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
        juego_continua = False
        # Devuelve el ganador (X o O)
    if diagonal_1:
        return board[0]
    elif diagonal_2:
        return board[2]
    else:
      return None


def verificar_si_empate():
    global juego_continua
    if "_" not in board:
       juego_continua = False
       return True
    else:    
       return False


def cambio_jugador():
    global actual_jugador
    # Si actual jugador fue X, luego cambia a O
    if actual_jugador == "X":
        actual_jugador = "O"
    # Si actual jugador fue O, luego cambia a X
    elif actual_jugador == "O":
        actual_jugador = "X"
    

jugar_juego()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this is a bit broad. Can you be more specific about what you've done to try to identify and solve the problem? What input are you giving when you execute the program? Do you get errors? If so, what are they? See [why is "can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: When I going to choose the position  from1 to 9 the board is not displayed. I don´t know why?

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is incorrect.

Here is the updated code:

```
def handle_turn(jugador):

    print(jugador + "turno.")
    posicion = input("Elegir una posicion desde 1 hasta 9 para comenzar: ")
    
    valid = False
    while not valid:

        while posicion not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" ,"9"]:
            posicion = input("Por favor elegir una posicion desde 1 hasta 9 para jugar: ")
      
        posicion = int(posicion) - 1

        if board[posicion] == "_":
            valid = True
        else:
            print ("Esta posicion ya esta ocupada, elegir otra: ")

    
    board[posicion] = jugador
    
    display_board()
```